How to find overlap of two count distinct measures
I have the following LookML view for a BigQuery table called events. I am able to use this view to see the count of distinct users that made a purchase or had a login event on any given date; however, I would like to know the number of users that had a purchase and login on the same date. I am wondering if it would be possible to find the intersection of the distinct_purchase_users_list and distinct_login_users_list array measures to count the number of users that had both events on any given day or month.
In the following example, if I were to create an explore with the date dimension and distinct_login_and_purchase_users measure, user ID #1 should be counted in distinct_login_and_purchase_users since they had a login and purchase on 10/1.



user_id
date
event_name




1
2024-10-01
'login'


1
2024-10-01
'purchase'


2
2024-10-01
'purchase'


3
2024-10-02
'login'


4
2024-10-02
'login'


5
2024-10-03
'purchase'



view: user_events {
  sql_table_name: `project.dataset.events` ;;

  dimension: date {
    type: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.date ;;
  }

  dimension: month {
    type: date
    sql: DATE_TRUNC(${TABLE}.date, MONTH) ;;
  }

  dimension: user_id {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.user_id ;;
  }

  dimension: event_name {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.event_name ;;
  }

  measure: distinct_purchase_users {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: CASE WHEN ${event_name} = 'purchase' THEN ${user_id} END ;;
  }

  measure: distinct_login_users {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: CASE WHEN ${event_name} = 'login' THEN ${user_id} END ;;
  }

  measure: distinct_login_and_purchase_users {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: ??? ;;
  }

  measure: distinct_purchase_users_list {
    type: string
    sql: ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ${event_name} = 'purchase' THEN ${user_id} END) ;;
  }

  measure: distinct_login_users_list {
    type: string
    sql: ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ${event_name} = 'login' THEN ${user_id} END) ;;
  }
}


The task is: calculating of distinct users who had both events ('login' and 'purchase' ) at the same date.  If user only had one event from these both - he should not be counted.
Try this code for this:
    measure: distinct_login_and_purchase_users {
      type: number
      sql:
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
         FROM (
           SELECT user_id
           FROM `project.dataset.events` AS sub
           WHERE sub.date = ${date}
             AND sub.event_name IN ('login', 'purchase')
           GROUP BY user_id
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub.event_name) = 2
         )
        ) ;;
    }

If we consider the task in general, in isolation from the LookML views,
here is the query for counting full information per date (with dates where no such events at all)
    with
    
    events as(
      -- user 1 (twice) and user 4
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'login'      event_name union all
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'purchase'   event_name union all     
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'login'      event_name union all
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'purchase'   event_name union all     
    select 2    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'purchase'   event_name union all
    select 3    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'login'      event_name union all
    select 4    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'login'      event_name union all
    select 4    user_id , '2024-10-01' date,    'purchase'   event_name union all
    
    -- user 1 again
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-02' date,    'login'      event_name union all
    select 1    user_id , '2024-10-02' date,    'purchase'   event_name union all     
    select 5    user_id , '2024-10-02' date,    'purchase'   event_name  union all
    select 6    user_id , '2024-10-02' date,    'purchase'   event_name  union all
    
    -- no users
    select 7    user_id , '2024-10-03' date,    'logout'   event_name 
    ),
      
    filtering_users as (
      select
          date,
          user_id
      from events
      where
         events.event_name in ('login', 'purchase')
      group by 
          date,
          user_id
          having count(distinct event_name) = 2
    ),
     count_users as (
        select
          date,
          count(distinct user_id) count_login_and_purchase
        from filtering_users
        group by date
    ),

    all_dates as (
      select distinct date from events
    )

    select
      date, 
      ifnull(count_login_and_purchase,0) count_login_and_purchase
    from count_users
    right join all_dates using (date)


This code uses LookML modeling, specifically filtered measures, rather than resorting directly to custom SQL. It has not been fully tested and may not yield the exact results you need, but it serves as a useful starting point.

Example with Filters

    measure: login_events {
      type: count
      filters: [event_name: "login"]
    }
    
    measure: purchase_events {
      type: count
      filters: [event_name: "purchase"]
    }
    
    measure: distinct_login_and_purchase_users {
      type: count_distinct
      sql: ${user_id} ;;
      filters: [login_events: "> 0", purchase_events: "> 0"]
    }



Using Self-Joins in the Explore

Another approach would be to add self-joins within the explore to create two versions of the dataset, each filtered for the respective events:

I do not think it is possible to include other measures as filters to a measure.
